# How to show $n\log n\in O(n^{3/2})$ without using limits.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, asymptotics

> How to show $n\log n\in O(n^{3/2})$ without using limits?

By not using limits, I mean, not use any calculus and prove starting from the definition ; for some $c > 0$, there is $n_0$ s.t for all $n\geq n_0$, $n\log n< c n^{3/2}$.

I really don't see what to do.

Comment: I'm not sure what your definition of $\log(n)$ is, here. What are we allowed to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We aim to show that there exists $N\in \Bbb N$ and $C$ such that for all $n\ge N$ the inequality
$$
n\log n \le Cn^{3/2} \iff \log n \le Cn^{1/2}
$$
holds. Since $\exp$ is a strictly increasing function, the above inequality
will hold if and only if
$$
n \le e^{Cn^{1/2}}
$$
holds. Now use the fact that $e^x \ge x^2$ holds for all sufficiently large $x$ to show that the above inequality holds with $C = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n\geq 1$
$$\log n=\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x}\stackrel{\text{Cauchy-Schwarz}}{\leq}\sqrt{\int_{1}^{n}1\,dx \int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x^2}}=\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
hence you may just take $c=1$ and $n_0=1$.

Comment: > "By not using limits, I mean, not use any calculus and prove starting from the definition."

I'd imagine integrals and CS are out of the question.

Comment: To prove that for any blah blah there is some blah blah ensuring blah blah for any blah blah **is** doing Calculus. There is no possible definition of $O(n^{3/2})$ (or $\log n$) which completely avoids Calculus.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'll agree that defining $\log$ requires calculus, but it's really not the case for big-O notation; $x_n=O(y_n)$ iff $|x_n|\le Cy_n$ for some constant $C$. I think a precalculus high schooler would be able to show that $n=O(n^2)$, once you told them what that meant.

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris And how do you define $\log$ without Calculus?

Comment: @N.S. See my comment on the original question.